# w many different two-pair five-card hands can be dealt from a standard deck of cards?

Tags: probability, combinations

I've asked two questions now, but this should be the last one.

So the way I see it is this.  You have 13 cards, you choose one. There are 4 choose ways you can choose the pair for this.  Then from 12 cards, you choose another one. There are 4 choose 2 ways to choose how this car will be in a pair. Lastly, there are 11 card types to choose from, and we need 3 of them, so 11 choose 3. Then I get as my answer:

$$_{13}C_1 \cdot _4C_2 \cdot _{12}C_1 \cdot _4C_2 \cdot _{11}C_3 \cdot 4^3$$

But this is exactly twice what the correct answer is... Why is this? Thanks!

Comment: When you say "two-pair," do you mean to exclude a full house?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the two ranks for the pairs at once.  There are
$${13\choose 2}$$ ways to do this.  You use $13\cdot 2$ which is an overcount by a factor of 2.

Comment: Sorry, but why would you have to choose the two ranks at once? Why not do them separately? I mean, we're still following order since we're doing the pairs first, and then, assuming there is now less numbers, we do the last number last (11 choose 3). So there is still an element of order to this.  Why CAN'T we say that we have 13 numbers to choose from for the first pair, then 12 to choose from for the second pair?  I have a lot of questions as this has been frustrating me why I can't just Get it.....

Comment: A pair of kings and a pair of jacks is the same as a pair of jacks and a pair of kings.

Comment: That does make sense.  Thank you! I got to practice some more now!